# Show that $T$ is a stopping time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stopping-times

Show that $$T = \inf \left \{n \geq 0|X_n \in \left \{0, N \right \} \right \}$$ is a stopping time with respect to $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_0,...,X_n)$ for $n\geq 0$.

I am fairly new to stopping times. From my understanding, I need to show that every set $\left \{T\leq n \right \}$ is a element in the filtration. My problem is that I intuitively do not know how to do this and why I am doing it other than thats the definition of the stopping time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to show that for every $n,$ $\{T\le n\}\in \mathcal F_n.$

Observe that $\{T\le n\}=\bigcup_{k\le n}\{X_k \in\{0,N\}\}.$

Can you show that, for $k\le n,$ $\{X_k\in \{0,N\}\}\in \mathcal F_k\subseteq \mathcal F_n?$

**Edit**

A few more details as per the comments.

If we want to break it down further, $\{X_k\in \{0,N\}\}= \{X_k=0\}\cup \{X_k=N\},$ so we're done if we can show that in general, $\{X_k=j\}\in \mathcal F_k$ for any $k.$ But this is more-or-less clear from the definition of $\mathcal F_k,$ since by the definition of $\sigma(X_k)$ (i.e. the smallest sigma algebra with respect to which $X_k$ is measurable), we have $\{X_k=j\}\in\sigma(X_k) \subseteq \mathcal F_k.$

Comment: I find myself somewhat in the same ditch show $\left \{X_k \in \left \{ 0,N \right \} \right \} \in \mathcal{F}_k$ as to $\left \{T \leq n\right \}\in \mathcal{F}_n$.  However $\mathcal{F}_k\subseteq  \mathcal{F}_n$ makes sense as by definition of the filtration.

Comment: Sorry for the edits formatting was incorrect.

Comment: @QWER Can break it down further... $\{X_k\in \{0,N\}\}=\{X_k = 0\}\cup \{X_k=N\}.$ What is the definition of $\sigma(X_0\,\ldots, X_k)$?

Comment: It would be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated from each of $X$'s in the sequence.

Comment: Sure, but what does it mean to be generated from $X_k$? Is it it clear that, say, $\{X_k=0\}\in \sigma( X_k)$?

Comment: Yes since we would have that $X_k\in\sigma$ by the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: @QWER I added to the answer. The fact that $\{X_k=0\}$ and $\{X_k=N\}$ are in $\mathcal F_k$ suffices to establish the result is due to the definition of a $\sigma$ algebra, but the reason that $\{X_k=0\}\in \mathcal F_k$ is true is because $X_k$ is $\mathcal F_k$-measurable, by the definition of $\mathcal F_k.$